# overflow y is set visible but behaves like scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, dropdown

I have set overflow-y : visible but it acts like scroll. I need overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: visible. How can I set them both? my table need horizontal scrollbar. I have a dropdown list. but dropdown list is floating inside the table it is not coming outwards. while dropdown is appearing vertical scroll bar also coming

Comment: cant see the drowdowns in your example, but floating an absolute positioned element is not logicly correct

Comment: @Rmaxx I have added dropdown but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if we give `overflow-y: visible; overflow-x: scroll;` then it will not work both will act as overflow scroll.